# Html form encoding on hippo cms not working with utf-8

Tags: java, servlets, encoding, hippocms

I am using freemarker as the templating engine for hippo cms. I pretty much followed http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/web-application/enabling-freemarker-template-support.html
 Unfortunately all forms are having encoding problems.

On [How to set content-type in Freemarker views when using Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302047/how-to-set-content-type-in-freemarker-views-when-using-spring-mvc) I double checked my utf-8 configuration again. German Umlauts still appear as jibberish in the request parameters (debugged in the spring CharacterEncodingFilter).

Changing the charset of the form to the following works.

```
<form action="${actionLink}" method="post" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">...</form>
```

This means that something in hippo is still configured working with ISO-8859-1 I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short:
The filter maping from the spring CharacterEncodingFilter was defined after the hstFilter which definately makes no sense.

Reminder: ordering of the filters are determined by the filter maping not the filter declaration