# Russian text displaying as ??? in my FTL-page

Tags: spring, freemarker

I use Spring MVC and Freemarker 2.3.27 in my web application, when I try to display russian text, I have only "?????". I saved my ftl-page in utf-8 and added meta:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>Registration</title>
        <#assign contextPath = request.contextPath>
    </head>
    <body>

                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Зарегистрируйтесь</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form method="post"  action="" name="saveUser">
                        <input name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" type="hidden">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <@spring.bind "userForm.username"/>
                            <div class="alert-link">
                               <#if spring.status.error>
                                   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                      <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error>
                                         <li>${error}</li>
                                      </#list>
                                   </div>
                               </#if>
                            </div>
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" name="username">
                        </div>

                        ...
                    </form>
                </div>

<body/>
<html/>
```

Here is my WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "aquaplant")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
.....
    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer getFreeMarkerConfigurer() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new DefaultFreeMarkerConfigurer();
        configurer.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        configurer.setTemplateLoaderPaths("/", "/WEB-INF/views");
        return configurer;
    }
    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource getMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:validation");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        //messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

In my entire program I use utf-8.
It should work but it doesn't. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Where's the Russian text? Is it directly entered into the template, or is it coming from somewhere else and inserted with `${...}`? Also, maybe https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_questionmark helps.

Comment: I have both cases for insertion russian text.

Comment: Define "something else", please, and maybe update the question. :) Is it properties files, by any chance?

Comment: I read the information on the link https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_questionmark , but did not find the answer to my question. In my entire program I use utf-8, but this doesn't.

Comment: Properties files are not usually encoded in UTF-8. It might be a red herring, it might not be. If you've created your properties files in an IDE, chances are they are not in the encoding you think they are. (Try to verify it, e.g. in Notepad++.) Apart from that, it might just be that your web browser decided to use a different encoding for whatever reason. In Firefox, you can check what encoding it assumed by opening its View menu (via Alt key)... Last but not least: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7302103/2018047

Comment: As it also occurs when the russian text is inserted from an outer source, it's not (or not only) a problem with how FreeMarker loads templates. It prints them in UNICODE (UTF-16 actually), so the loss is not there either. The question is if how the servlet container encodes the UNICODE text... the default is often ISO-8859-1, not UTF-8. But that's what the FAQ says too. Are you 100% sure the servlet container is set up correctly?

Comment: How can i check and change the servlet container encoding?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by creating such a filter:

```
public class CharsetFilter implements Filter {

    private String encoding;
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        encoding = filterConfig.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");
        if (encoding == null) encoding = "UTF-8";
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (request.getCharacterEncoding()==null) {
            request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        }
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

This filter must be added to servletContext:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        CharsetFilter filter = new CharsetFilter();
        servletContext.addFilter("charsetFilter", filter).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(SpringConfig.class, WebConfig.class);
        context.setServletContext(servletContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher11 = servletContext.
                addServlet("dispatcher11", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher11.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher11.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```